# Problem while setting proxy using angular and node

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular6

I am new in angular 6. I am setting up my project using angular and node. While setting I am stucking in a problem. What i got error is :

```
 Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api from localhost:4200 to http://localhost:5555 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

I know there are many question regarding this, but i could not find the answer.

Here is proxy.config file

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:5555",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

Here is my node file:

```
var app = require('./app.js');
var debug = require('debug')('mean-app:server');
var http = require('http');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
function normalizePort(val) {
   var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    return port;
   }

   return false;
}
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '5555');
app.set('port', port);
 app.get('/api/testapi', function response(req, res) {

  res.send({"test":"test"})
 }) 

var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
server.on('listening', onListening);

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  console.log('Listening on ' + port);
}
```

Comment: It seems that you don't have an endpoint that starts with `/api/` in your node file

Comment: Can you also add how you call this api from your angular application?

Comment: I am just hitting the url in browser: http://localhost:4200/api/testapi

Answer (score 0):

This solves your issue.

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
{
    context: [
        "/api"
    ],
    target: "http://localhost:5555",
    secure: false
}
]

 module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

Comment: where we add this?

Comment: While running your app provide this file as proxy.conf.js.        ng serve  - -proxy-config proxy.conf.js